# Is it appropriate to put blocking (without O_NONBLOCK) file desciptors to select/poll in Linux?

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, select-syscall

```
man select
```

> BUGS
>
> Under  Linux, select() may report a socket file descriptor as "ready
>   for reading", while nevertheless a subsequent read blocks.  This could
>   for example happen when data has arrived but upon examination has
>   wrong checksum  and  is discarded.   There may be other circumstances
>   in which a file descriptor is spuriously reported as ready.  Thus it
>   may be safer to use O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should not block.

But I see `netcat`, `socat`, `wget` (but not `curl`) putting FDs without O_NONBLOCK to select or poll.

I've implemented a [special library](https://github.com/vi/libselectfuzz) to test apps for this and they are failing...

/* Inspired by seeing a hung `wget` that was `read`ing from a stale socket and not timing out like it should */

Should I report this as bugs or they are doing it it right?

Possible answers:

1. "No, blocking FD in poll/select => bug";
2. "Only AF_INET[6] sockets can misfire on select, so a bug only if a blocking network socket is in poll/select";
3. "Yes, report bugs only if/when you see a real-world failure because of this" (like in wget).

Comment: Is there a function to tell how many bytes are available for reading, and is that function in those applications called and it's result checked before calling recv?

Comment: The select and poll functions return how many filehandles _maybe_ available for reading. I don't remember about function to get available bytes.

Comment: The function to see how many bytes are available is the traditional `ioctl` example: `ioctl(socket,FIONREAD,&rbytes);`
Or the return value from `read` or `recvfrom` or anything ...

Comment: If an application uses blocking sockets isn't a bug ... this is the way they want to handle the connections. The non blocking sockets are useful on multi-tasking/threading applications and i don't think `netcat`, `socat`, `wget` are one of these applications ... i'm not sure ... never needed to check.

Comment: The problem is not blocking sockets by itself, but trusting select/poll output and thinking "this time this read won't block". Blocking FDs are good for multi-threaded things.